# Importing a class in a class that imports the previous class (import-ception)

Tags: python, import

I'm trying to write a large class called `Networking` in a separate python file called `networking.py` to provide some helper methods. I can import that class in my `main.py`, however, I would like my networking class to be able to call a method in my `main.py` (`Main` class). It won't seem to let me use:

```
from main import Main
```

I'm guessing it will cause some type of import-ception paradox. So how can I go about doing this. I only need to call a single method in `Main` once from `Networking`, but `Main` will call multiple methods in `Networking`.

**main.py**

```
from networking import Networking

class Main:

    Networking.get("Test")

    def receive(st):
        print("Received : "+st)
        Networking.push(st + "123")
```

**networking.py**

```
class Networking:

    @staticmethod
    def get(st):
        print("Requesting parameter (" + st + ") from smartphone")
        receive(st) #method in Main

    @staticmethod
    def push(st):
        print("Sending  (" + st + ")  to smartphone")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, when you import a module (or part of it) for the first time, the code inside the module is executed like any other code. That is, if you had some `print`s laying around in global scope, they would be executed on import.

In your case, when you're running `main.py`, your first instruction is to import `networking`, which is fine so far. Then, you importing `networking` (and read/execute the module), and the first instruction of the networking file is to import the main module. That's where things start to go bad. The `main` module hasn't been imported yet, so it'll try to import it, and by doing so, execute it once again. The first instruction of the `main` module is to import `Networking` from the `networking` module. It doesn't need to import `networking` now since it's already been imported... Right? But when it tries to import the `Networking` class from that module, it fails - Networking doesn't exist because it has not been defined yet (remember, we still haven't read/executed anything past `networking.py`'s first instruction (`import`).

To better illustrate this, here is the output you get if you add `Executing first line of *xxx.py*, *before/after* import` to the top of your module (before and after the `import` instruction). As you can see, it never gets through the import sequence - and you can see it crashes while trying to import `Network` from `networking`, just as explained above:

```
Executing first line of main.py, before import
Executing first line of networking.py, before import
Executing first line of main.py, before import
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from networking import Networking
  File "D:\Users\Matt\Desktop\networking.py", line 2, in <module>
    from main import Main
  File "D:\Users\Matt\Desktop\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from networking import Networking
ImportError: cannot import name Networking
```

In summary, you shouldn't use circular imports in Python. Refactor your modules so that circular imports are not required.

---

If you **really** cannot refactor your modules, here is an hack to get around your problem.

**main.py**

```
# No change here
from networking import Networking

class Main:
    Networking.get("Test")

    @staticmethod
    def receive(st):
        print("Received : "+st)
        Networking.push(st + "123")
```

**networking.py**

```
# Define a Main class with an empty `receive` method
class Main: 
    @staticmethod
    def receive(st):
        pass

# Define your Networking class normally
class Networking: 
    @staticmethod
    def get(st):
        print("Requesting parameter (" + st + ") from smartphone")
        Main.receive(st)

    @staticmethod
    def push(st):
        print("Sending  (" + st + ")  to smartphone")

# Import your main module after `Networking` has been defined
from main import Main
```

**Output**

```
Requesting parameter (Test) from smartphone
Requesting parameter (Test) from smartphone
Received : Test
Sending  (Test123)  to smartphone
```

Importing `main` after `Networking` has been defined will allow the `network.Network` import in the main module to work. Then the empty `Main` class is redefined and overwrites your fake one, which allows you to use the real Main class when `Networking.get(st)` is finally called.

As I said before, it's a bit hack-ish, so you really should consider refactoring your modules instead. ;-)

Comment: So what's the best solution? can I decide when the import is called?

Comment: As I said in my post, the best solution is to refactor your modules so you don't need to use circular imports. If you want a very hacky way of doing things, I have one, which I'll append to my post in a second, but I repeat, you should really design your modules so that circular imports are not required. ;-)

Comment: @TurtleFan added a hack to get around the circular import problem.

Comment: Thanks man! I will refactor but it's nice to have quick fix so I can keep working for a bit